# Layout mobile quebrado

Tags: bug, status-pronto, design

Uma imagem vale mais que mil palavras:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

iPhone 5, iOS 9

Comment: Não tem descrição, -1 :p

Comment: Brincadeira hehe você não é o unico, testei aqui nos 2 navegadores mobile, está identico, parece que atualizaram algo hoje, porque antes não estava assim.

Comment: A minha também está direita no Android 4 com Chrome: http://i.imgur.com/EorWgzb.jpg

Comment: Acho que fizeram rollback na versão anterior, voltou ao normal.